# MySQL keeps crashing while using Jira

Tags: windows, mysql, jira

I have a Jira install running on Windows using MySQL database hosted on the same instance. We're having an issue where the MySQL service keeps crashing (after a few page requests). We've been running in this same configuration without issue for months. This is a recent problem.

The error I pulled from the event viewer is:

> Faulting application name: mysqld.exe, version: 5.5.28.0, time stamp:
> 0x503ddca5 Faulting module name: mysqld.exe, version: 5.5.28.0, time
> stamp: 0x503ddca5 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
> 0x00000000002ee7e1 Faulting process id: 0x440 Faulting application
> start time: 0x01ce1791d135feaa Faulting application path: C:\Program
> Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe Faulting module path:
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe Report Id:
> f1294be0-8385-11e2-93fe-00155d502a64 Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

Here's the setup:

- Hardware:  Windows Azure Virtual Machine (Tiny - 768mb/shared CPU)
- OS: Windows Server 2012 Datacenter 64-bit
- Web Server: Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
- Jira: v5.2.5 (GreenHopper v6.1.3.1)
- MySQL Connector J: 5.1.10
- MySQL: 5.5.28.0

Failed work-around attempts:

- Increase the size of the server (tried up to 4-cores, 3GB)
- Restart the MySQL service (it just dies again after a few requests)

---

*Edit for Comment: 1*

The MySQL Logs seem to be repeating the as I restarted the service and then crashed it shortly after:

> 130302 20:48:39 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 130302 20:48:40 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 130302 20:48:40 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>
> 130302 20:48:40 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 130302 20:48:40 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
>
> 130302 20:48:40 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 130302 20:48:40 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> 130302 20:48:43  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
>
> 130302 20:48:44 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 17878576
>
> 130302 20:48:44 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
>
> 130302 20:48:44 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
>
> 130302 20:48:44 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
>
> 130302 20:48:46 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>
> 130302 20:48:46 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
>
> Version: '5.5.28-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>
> 130302 20:56:04  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 648 in file fut0lst.ic line 83
>
> InnoDB: Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA
>
> InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
>
> InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
>
> InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
>
> InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
>
> InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
>
> InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
>
> InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
>
> InnoDB: Thread 1532 stopped in file os0sync.c line 474
>
> InnoDB: Thread 1536 stopped in file os0sync.c line 781
>
> InnoDB: Thread 1544 stopped in file ut0ut.c line 76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [copying the latest version](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+JIRA+to+MySQL#ConnectingJIRAtoMySQL-2.CopytheMySQLJDBCdrivertoyourapplicationserver) of [MySQL Connector J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) (v5.1.23), the MySQL service no longer crashes and everything appears to be working as normal. It appears that there was an issue with the version I was using.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.chriscalender.com/?tag=innodb-assertion-failure) seems to describe your problem.
If I understand correctly your databse is corrupt and needs rebuilding.